# How to use OpenCV test framework to run specific tests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, opencv

OpenCV provides unit tests for its important functions. In order to do that, it provides a unit test framework, which is built on top of gtest. However, the documentation on this test framework is really limited as it is not supposed to be used outsider OpenCV. I tried to manage to use OpenCV test framework based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405601/how-do-i-use-opencvs-test-framework-with-cmake). However, I cannot make the test framework only run specific test functions I wrote due to lack of documentation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally find the solution: use `--gtest_filter=` option from the command line of the test program. This comes from the fact that OpenCV unit test is an improved version of GTEST.